# Disassembling Scala code

Tags: scala, disassembly

How can I disassemble Scala code? Can it be done without first building the Jar and decompiling the resulting `.class` files? Is there an alternative, faster way to do this?

For Python there is [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html)  which can be used as follows:

```
def myfunc(alist):
    return len(alist)

>>> dis.dis(myfunc)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (len)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (alist)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You know you can do this in the REPL:

```
scala> def foo[A](xs: Seq[A]) = xs.size
foo: [A](xs: Seq[A])Int

scala> :javap foo
  Size 714 bytes
...
public <A extends java/lang/Object> int foo(scala.collection.Seq<A>);
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC
  Code:
    stack=1, locals=2, args_size=2
     0: aload_1       
     1: invokeinterface #20, 1 // InterfaceMethod scala/collection/Seq.size:()I
     6: ireturn       
...
```

You have crawl a bit through the output because it contains the outer module and many more information.

Comment: The syntax `:javap #foo` works for this case. If you have `C` with member `c`, then `C#c`.

Comment: Great thanks! This is going to save me a lot of time. For anyone struggling with `javap` in the Scala REPL (I had the warning `:javap unavailable on this system`) be sure to have the latest version installed. I had version 2.9.2 and not even adding `tools.jar` to the classpath worked. This has been fixed in the later versions. As of now I have version 2.11.6 installed.

Comment: You can also just do `def greet() = "hello"` then `:javap greet`